# Ember Route now is singleton ? Needs confirmation

Tags: ember.js, routes

I'm using Ember 1.13.3, and somehow I noticed now that Route is also singleton (?), just like controller.

I was checking it because I notice a bug in my app since I upgraded to 1.13.3, and to confirm my suspicion I added console.log in the init method..., and saw that init method is called only once for the route (I switched to another route and wend back).

Is it new (in Ember 1.13, and onward) ?

I need the confirmation if route is really singleton now, in order to rule out the possibility that this behavior I was observing was due to certain (mis)programming (my code).

Thanks,
Raka

Comment: I am not 100% sure it's a singleton (it does look like). In any case, if you were relying on `init` you may want to update your code to use the `activate`/`deactivate` events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are routes and controllers classes and not objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672870/why-are-routes-and-controllers-classes-and-not-objects)

Comment: This is new to me (I mean the fact that Route is now singleton). I already knew that Controller is singleton though. It somehow does affect my existing code (upon upgrading to ember 1.13.3). Anyway, just checking if it's just me, but I guess my question is confirmed now.